# Airflow: Dynamic Task Mapping: Expand on results of any upstream task, not only previous one

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

Airflow 2.7 documentation for [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html) states that "mapped tasks are created based on the output of a **previous** task".

Nothing is said in docs and examples about how to create mapped task based on output of *any other upstream task*, not only previous one.

For example, trying to create a DAG like this: **A >> B >> C[]**, where **C[]** should be mapped based on results of **A** (not **B**) creates additional *A >> C[]* dependency, which I don't need. See [Graph view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJhfs.png)

Code example:

```
from airflow.decorators import dag, task, task_group
from datetime import datetime
import random as rnd

@task
def A():
    return [x for x in range(int(rnd.random()*10)+1)]

@task
def B():
    print("intermediate")

@task
def C(x):
    return x + 10

@dag(dag_id="TEST_DYNAMIC_SIMPLE",start_date=datetime(2023, 10, 11), catchup=False,schedule=None,tags=["TESTS"])
def TEST_DYNAMIC_SIMPLE():
    tA = A()
    exC = C.expand(x=tA)
    tA >> B() >> exC

globals()["TEST_DYNAMIC_SIMPLE"] = TEST_DYNAMIC_SIMPLE() 

# Local test
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag = globals()['TEST_DYNAMIC_SIMPLE']        
    dag.test()
```

Comment: What's wrong with passing arguments of `A` through `B` to make them exposed as mapping source for `C`?

Comment: Usability and DevEx. Correct way is r

Comment: Making `C` being expanded through `A` without explicit dependency is definitely not about usability and clarity. You may try to use `xcom_pull` for `A`'s output as expand source for task `C`

Comment: Sorry. My previous comment was incomplete. We're testing Airflow in Use-Case where a Dag hierarchy is defined in legacy system (dag has 116 tasks and 28 groups) and we just want to run it. Thus, I've generated a Dag from parent-child hierarchy. Problem is with tasks that are parallelized in legacy system. Number of parallel task instances is dynamic, but depends on first init task. So: (1) Why DataFlow and Control Flow where joined in MappedTasks? (2) Why not to use XCom.pull() for expand()? In our case this will let first task to push data for expand() of other tasks. Result: UX and DevEx

Comment: It is not clear how should you distinguish input between parallel mapped TIs when they are expanded over result of independent task. I cannot tell anything about `xcom_pull` approach from different task, because we use taskflow in our design and it builds dependency implicitly, but this design will be unlear at least. Why not to pass individual parameters between all tasks that should be expanded and provide explicit dependencies? It's common way to do. About your first question: Airflow is a scheduler with UI, it performs actions in predefined order and there's no dataflow functionality in it